# DB Facade is not reading .env values

Tags: mysql, laravel, environment-variables, lumen

I have a docker containter running my web app (developed with Lumen). The web app, needs access to a MySQL database located in the docker container host machine.

The IP Address are:

- Docker Container 172.17.0.1
- Mysql Host 192.168.0.9

So, in the Lumen project .env file i configured the following value; DB_HOST=192.168.0.9
But i when call the DB connection an exception is throwed:

```
DB::connection()->getPdo();
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.2'
>   (using password: YES)

Why Lumen DB Facade is not reading the variable correctly ?

My .env file is:

```
APP_NAME=BeOmnichannel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost:8082
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL=

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=192.168.0.9
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=omnichannel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=whitehawk

CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync

TEST_VAR=Foo
```

Comment: Did you cleared config cache ?, in case you did not `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I think the credentials are wrong.

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI `config:clear` is not available in Lumen installation.

Comment: @hmrneves the problem is that Eloquent try to connect to another host but, why ?

Comment: Cant figure it out... But, have you tried ```DB::connection('con_name')->...```? I thing its suitable too. Btw, show us your env file please. If you reconfigured ```config\database. Php``` show us too.

Comment: @hmrneves i tried setting the connection name but, didn't work

Comment: I edited the comment. See it please.

Comment: @hmrneves i posted the .env file. I haven't got defined a `config\database.php` file.

Comment: Try. First change host to ```mysql```, clear cache and try again. If doesn't work, try chsnging the port to 33060, clear cache and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL installation, in the host machine, didn't allow remote connections.
I created an user with permissions to connect remotely and now, Lumen can access to the database.